# Problema com o C

Tags: c

Estou com o `[Error] expected expression before '<=' token`, com o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    float VS, VF;
    printf ("valor do salario: ");
    scanf ("%f", &VS);
    printf ("valor de um financiamento: ");
    scanf ("%f", &VF);
    if (VF/VS)<=5
    printf ("“Financiamento concedido.");
    else
    printf ("Financiamento negado.");
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

agora o programa esta pulando a resposta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você quis dizer com pulando a resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente substituir:

```
if (VF/VS)<=5
```

por

```
if ((VF/VS)<=5)
```

O erro acontece pois o *if* está esperando encontrar uma expressão do tipo *boolean* (verdadeiro ou falso) dentro dos parênteses que o sucedem, e no seu caso ele está encontrando uma divisão (valor numérico).

Quanto ao segundo "erro", a "resposta" está aparecendo antes da mensagem do `system ("PAUSE");`. Para consertar isso substitua:

```
printf ("“Financiamento concedido.");
```

por

```
printf ("Financiamento concedido.\n");
```

Onde o `\n` representa quebra de linha.

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria dar uma estudadinha a mais na linguagem, para evitar ficar postando aqui cada erro que o compilador apresenta.

Comment: o único problema que tenho que mesmo eu solucionando isto eu comecei a poco tempo por isso não tenho experiencia com os erros apresentados pra min.

Comment: @Cache Isso se encaixa como um comentário, não uma resposta. Mas você está certo.

Comment: Desculpe se pareci um pouco rude, não foi minha intenção. Não sei qual material você está usando para estudo, mas creio que lá deve ter alguns exemplos básicos sobre o uso de parênteses e condições compostas.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, consegui solucionar meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

O teu erro está neste `if`:

```
if (VF/VS)<=5
```

Tenta:

```
if ((VF/VS)<=5)
```